# How do I change the random_number variable every time I click the button?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

> import random 
>   from tkinter import * 
>   root = Tk()
>
> random_number = str(random.randint(1,11))
>
> def myClick():
>       myLable = Label(root, text=f"{random_number}")
>       myLable.pack()
>
> rand_button = Button(root, text="Press for a random number",
>   command=myClick) 
>   rand_button.pack()
>
> root.mainloop()

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
import random
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
random_number = str(random.randint(1, 11))
MyLabel = Label(Tk, text=random_number)
MyLabel.pack()
def myclick():
    random_number = str(random.randint(1, 11)) # Assigning random number
    MyLabel.config(text=random_number) # Changing text to random number

randButton = Button(root, text="Press for a random number", command=myClick)
randButton.pack()
root.manloop()
```

The main problem with your code was that you had to make a new random number every time you clicked the button and you had to change the text of the same label, or you would have a bunch of labels stacking on each other.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a random number to the `random_number` variable once, so it never changes.

If you move it to the method it will generate a new one each time.

```
import random from tkinter import * root = Tk()

def myClick():
    random_number = str(random.randint(1,11))  # Generates a new # when the method is called.
    myLable = Label(root, text=f"{random_number}") myLable.pack()

    rand_button = Button(root, text="Press for a random number", command=myClick) 
    rand_button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```